# How to calculate velocity on each axis having angles?

Tags: c, trigonometry

I have a 3D space where I can move my spaceship right/left and up/down with mouse. I'm able to calculate speed of the spaceship on a plane, having the facing (alfa angle), like:

```
float cosf = cos(alfa * M_PI/180.0);
float sinf = sin(alfa * M_PI/180.0);

vxm = + cosf*vx - sinf*vz;
vym = vy;
vzm = + sinf*vx + cosf*vz;
```

However I'm having trouble when adding a Beta angle (the vertical facing of ship), how can I calculate the three velocities on each axis, having Alfa and Beta angle?

Comment: Isn't this one for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If magnitude of velocity is V and Beta is angle between V direction and OXY plane, then

```
v_z = V * Sin(Beta)
v_x = V * Cos(Beta) * Cos(Alpha)
v_y = V * Cos(Beta) * Sin(Alpha)
```